# websocket request in timeout using fiddler

Tags: javascript, websocket, webpack, timeout, angular-cli

I am using angularcli server and fiddler as a proxy to handle windows authentication. Everything is fine except a timeout on a websocket request:

ws://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/754/wgnopkw5/websocket

when fiddler is off, the websocket works fine, when on, the websocket doesn't work anymore.
I really need to have fiddler on. I cannot find out what could cause this error.

Has anybody any idea about such an error?

the strange thing is that I can see the websocket request in fiddler and its response as if it worked!

After further investigations, it seems the problem occurs only with chrome. IE seems to work fine...

Thanks

Comment: Something to be wary of is the fact that Fiddler starts a proxy server when it is running. Perhaps you have a chrome proxy extension which is interfering with Fiddler.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actualy this is the proxy feature I am using on fiddler for this project, meaning I cannot deactivate it